# Trouble formatting json objects with lodash _.groupBy

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm having trouble reformatting an object in order to group by lists.

```
// input 
{
    'M': [
        {name: Bob, id: 1},
        {name: John, id: 2},
        {name: John, id: 3},
    ],
    'F': [
        {name: Liz, id: 4},
        {name: Mary, id: 5},
        {name: Mary, id: 6},
    ]
}

// desired output
{
    'M': [
        'Bob': [ {name: Bob, id: 1},]
        'John': [ {name: John, id: 2}, {name: John, id: 3} ]
    ],
    'F': [
        'Liz': [ {name: Liz, id: 4} ]
        'Mary': [ {name: Mary, id: 5}, {name: Mary, id: 6} ]
    ]
}
```

My current script is only returning the 'M' key and I'm not what is causing it

```
for (var key in obj) {
    var data = _.groupBy(obj[key], 'name')
    return data;
}
```

I've also tried

```
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(obj, key => {
    var data = _.groupBy(obj[key], 'name')
    return data;
  })
```

but it throws `TypeError: #<Object> is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues) to group each gender groups by their names through [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy).

```
var output = _.mapValues(input, names => _.groupBy(names, 'name'));
```

```js
var input = {
    'M': [
        {name: 'Bob', id: 1},
        {name: 'John', id: 2},
        {name: 'John', id: 3},
    ],
    'F': [
        {name: 'Liz', id: 4},
        {name: 'Mary', id: 5},
        {name: 'Mary', id: 6},
    ]
};

var output = _.mapValues(input, names => _.groupBy(names, 'name'));

console.log(output);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use _.forOwn since you want to iterate its own properties.

```
_.forOwn(obj, function(key, val) {
    var ret = {};
    ret[key] = _.groupBy(val, 'name');
    return ret;
});
```